# Promise + jQuery Ajax chain makes memory grow. Am I using them correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory-leaks, promise

I have a JS that must perform a remote operation periodically, then react to it. The worflow is:

```
- Start the operation in main script
  -> `setInterval` calling a function every 5 seconds
     -> This function waits for a `Promise` that internally...
        -> ... calls `$.ajax`, validate the response, then resolve or reject.
```

I'm seeing memory growing in my app and this operation chain may be the cause. Am I using Promises the right way?

The main entry point is simply:

```
StateWatcher.startWatchSystem();
```

Then the involved modules:

```
var StateWatcher = {

    // is called by the main app to start the backround check every 5 sec
    // the actual function that performs the update is "doSystemStateUpdate"
    startWatchSystem: function() {    
        this.doSystemStateUpdate();
        this.systemWatchTimeout = setInterval(() => {
            this.doSystemStateUpdate();
        }, 5000)
    },

    <...>

    // this is "doSystemStateUpdate": the remote call is performed by another module "RemoteQuery.getSystemState()".
    // that last function returns a Promise (see below), so I can check the result with "then" and "catch"
    doSystemStateUpdate: function() {
        RemoteQuery.getSystemState()
        .then((data) => {
            // ok, got the new State
            this.currentSystemState = data.Message;
            // ... inform other modules etc etc...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            Logger.write("error", "doSystemStateUpdate:");
            Logger.write("error", error);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the "RemoteQuery" module:

```
var RemoteQuery = {

    connectionError: false,

    // the getSystemState internally calls jQuery AJAX but then enclose it in a Promise
    // When Ajax finishes, before actually resolve the promise it must do a quick check on the Ajax result, using function "validateResponse"
    getSystemState: function () { 
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: <.... http...>,
                method: "GET",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) { RemoteQuery.validateResponse(true, resolve, data) },
                error: function(xhr, opts, error) { RemoteQuery.validateResponse(false, reject, xhr) }
            });
        })
    }

    <...>

    // this is the last step: this function sets an "alarm" flag if the ajax operation was not ok.
    // at the end, it calls the function to resolve the promise
    validateResponse: function(ok, then, args) {
        if (this.connectionError == false && ok == false) {
            this.connectionError = true;
            // do other stuff (logging,...)
        }
        else if (this.connectionError == true && ok == true) {
            this.connectionError = false;
            // do other stuff (logging,...)
        }

        then(args); // now resolve or reject based on how it has been called after ajax->success or ajax->error
    },
}
```

Comment: so you want to request every 5 seconds even if the previous request did not finish yet?

Comment: also the ajax-docs stating that `.then()` promise is `An alternative construct to the success callback option` so i guess this is where your code "follows two directions" instead of doing everything in done()/then() or success()

Comment: Can't see anything that would cause a memory leak but you can simplify by writing `return $.ajax(...).then(...).catch(...)` and ditch the `new Promise()` wrapper. This pattern will also allow you to roll the `validateResponse()` code into `getSystemState()` and for `validateResponse()` response to disappear as a separate function. It's a better solution though I doubt it will fix your memory leak.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I've understood that I can replace the jQuery's error/success with then/catch (but why not with done/fail?)... anyway I'm not sure why this will allow me to remove `validateResponse()`. How can I roll it inside `getSystemState()`? It is used also by other function so I'm not confident to copy/paste its body there...
Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: If `validateResponse()` is called elsewhere then please ignore my suggestion. You should still use `.then()` & `.catch()` though. In jQuery v3+, they posess socalled "filtering power" which success:/error:` and .done()`& `.fail()` do not. With `.then()` & `.catch()` a returned value of a thrown error will propagate down a promise chain.